# SQL idiom for checking whether values in a column are uniform

Tags: sql, idioms

I want to check that all values in column c1 of a certain table, say t1, are the same. I do this with:

```
SELECT count(*)=1 
  FROM (
        SELECT c1 
          FROM t1 
      GROUP BY c1) AS t1_grouped;
```

is this the "right thing" to do, or is there some aggregate function or some other language construct for achieving the same (possibly with better performance even)?

Comment: Which system? What will you do with your output: just "human consumption", or use in a `CASE WHEN` or assign to a variable?

Comment: @DanielSparing: Any system, any DBMS. My output is not for human consumption, I run some queries to essentially pre-process certain columns for analytical work. But that's not very relevant to the question itself...

Comment: The reason I asked is that for similar statistics you can often use things like `SUM(a=0)` and this works in some systems and not all. And if you need a boolean variable as output that is often an extra step from just looking into if the result is 1 (integer) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on @Bohemian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22063644/1593077), it seems I can improve my query like so:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT c1)=1 FROM t1;
```

Much better!

Comment: At first I thought this wouldn't parse, but it does! You're right, it *is* much better :)

Comment: This won't parse on "any DBMS", though, but only on those that offer a boolean data type.

Comment: @AndriyM: I believe that ANSI-SQL-conformant database must support boolean values.

Answer (score 2):

This will tell you how many *different* values you have:

```
select count(distinct c1) from t1
```

If that number is `1`, then they are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is a nonsense (at least for me) to fill a table column with a same value (if I've understood correctly what you mean).
If you need to check value to be in a range or to obey some (business) rules use a trigger. Triggers are invented just for this purpose.

Comment: I disagree: you can very well say have a table with orders, with a flag whether the orders are processed or not. Then someone might be interested if there are running orders or all are taken care of already. etc etc.

Comment: Plus - don't shoot the messenger! I didn't say I had anything to do with filling that table.

Comment: Obviously I've misunderstood the question. Sorry.